# Exporting Android library to JAR and encrypting using progruard

Tags: android, ant, export, proguard

I would like to export one of my android library for our customer and obfuscate the code using progruard. For now, Google does not allow doing this. Has anyone tryed to do so? I think the option is to write my own ANT script